# Erro na criação de objeto Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

```
class Linha(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, valor):
        valor = int(valor)
        if valor >= 0:
            self._x = valor
        else:
            raise ValueError('Valor de x inválido !')

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._x

    @y.setter
    def y(self, valor):
        valor = int(valor)
        if valor >= 0:
            self._y = valor
        else:
            raise ValueError('Valor de y inválido !')

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%i - %i)' %(self.x, self.y)

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            x = input('X :')
            y = input('Y :')
            linha = Linha(x, y)
            print(linha)
        except ValueError as erro:
            print(erro)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Quando tento criar um objeto por exemplo:

linha = Linha(2, 8)

Ele cria um objeto linha com valores x = 2 e y = 2.

Onde está o erro ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está aqui:

```
@property
def y(self):
    return self._x
```

Você colocou _x, mas é _y.

Comment: Era isso mesmo nem vi esse erro na propriedade y.

Comment: @ThiagoThiaguinho: não esqueça de aceitar a resposta.